# Location of downloaded model when using Predictor.from_path in AllenNLP?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda, allennlp

I'm following AllenNLP's example code for [correference resolution](https://demo.allennlp.org/coreference-resolution), which has a method `Predictor.from_path`:

```py
from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor
import allennlp_models.tagging

predictor = Predictor.from_path("https://storage.googleapis.com/allennlp-public-models/coref-spanbert-large-2021.03.10.tar.gz")
```

I'm running this in a Jupyter notebook, in a conda environment.  When I execute the example snippet, the model file is downloaded, which is ~1.5gb in size.

I'm wondering where this file was downloaded to, so I can potentially clean it up if necessary?  It's not in `~/conda/env/<my env>`, `~/.jupyter`, `~/.local/share/jupyter/`, `/tmp`, or the working directory where the notebook is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes into `~/.allennlp/cache/`.